ember-cp-validations : re-run validator for model attribute which is dependent on another model attribute from the same model
Using ember-cp-validations, I am trying to re-run validator for my model attribute which is dependent on another model attribute from the same model, attrA which depends on attrB. I want to re-run the validator for attrA whenever attrB changes. Validator works if I enter the value for  attrB first, then I enter attrA. It works the other way (first enter attrA, then attrB) only if I  keep the focus on the attrA input field and focus out later after entering values for both the fields. Is there a way to trigger this validator for the 2nd case without the need of keeping the focus on the input and focus out later?
model validator
attrA: [
    validator('inline', {
      dependentKeys: ['model.attrB'],
      validate(value, options, model) {
        const holdTime = parseInt(value);
        const keepaliveInterval = parseInt(model.get('attrB'));
        if (holdTime < keepaliveInterval * 3) {
          return 'invalid input';
        }
        return true;
      }
    })
  ]

template and component code which triggers this validation
<input
  @placeholder={{180}}
  @inputType="number"
  @value={{model.attrA}}
  @validationFn={{fn this.validate "attrA"}}
/>

validate(path) {
    return { validations: model.validations.attrs[path] };
  }

